# Modify object via Python multiprocessing.Pool: strange behavior

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pickle, pool

I have an object with two attributes: a dict and an int. When I modify the object using a forked process via multiprocessing.Pool, I get back the object with it the modified int attribute, but the dict isn't modified. Why is that?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def fork():
    someObject = SomeClass()
    for i in range(10):
        someObject.method(i)    
    print("in fork, someObject has dct=%s and nbr=%i" % (someObject.dct, someObject.nbr))
    return someObject

def test():
    pool = Pool(processes=1)             
    result = pool.apply(func=fork)
    print("in main, someObject has dct=%s and nbr=%i" % (result.dct, result.nbr))

class SomeClass(object):
    dct = {}
    nbr = 0     
    def method(self, nbr):
        self.dct[nbr]=nbr
        self.nbr+=nbr

if __name__=='__main__':
    test()
```

Output:

in fork, someObject has dct={0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9} and nbr=45

in main, someObject has dct={} and nbr=45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parent process has a different copy of `SomeClass.dct` and `SomeClass.nbt` than the child process(es).

The reason `nbr` is updated but not `dct` is that `nbr` actually becomes an instance variable when you do `self.nbr+=nbr`, which gets pickled and sent back to the parent process. But you never assign `self.dct` to anything, so `self.dct` (which actually refers to `SomeClass.dct`) does not get pickled.

You can see this by defining a `__getstate__()` on `SomeClass`:

```
class SomeClass(object):
    dct = {}
    nbr = 0
    def method(self, nbr):
        self.dct[nbr]=nbr
        self.nbr+=nbr

    def __getstate__(self):
        res = self.__dict__
        print("pickled", res)
        return res
```

This prints:

```
in fork, someObject has dct={0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9} and nbr=45
('pickled', {'nbr': 45})
in main, someObject has dct={} and nbr=45
```

You can force `dct` to be pickled by assigning it to "itself":

```
class SomeClass(object):
    dct = {}
    nbr = 0
    def method(self, nbr):
        self.dct[nbr]=nbr
        self.dct = self.dct
        self.nbr+=nbr
```

This prints:

```
in fork, someObject has dct={0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9} and nbr=45
('pickled', {'nbr': 45, 'dct': {0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9}})
in main, someObject has dct={0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5, 6: 6, 7: 7, 8: 8, 9: 9} and nbr=45
```

Comment: You, sir, are the greatest. I spent several hours trying to figure this out. Thanks. I would like to understand why `self.dct[nbr]=nbr` doesn't "assign anything" though.

Comment: @DerekFarren What `self.nbr += nbr` does is: 1. read `self.nbr`, 2. add `nbr` to it, 3. assign the result back into `self.nbr`. In contrast, what `self.dct[nbr] = nbr` does is: 1. read `self.dct` (which is a reference to a `dict` object), 2. **mutate the state of the dict** by setting the key `nbr` to `nbr`. At no point do you actually assign the dict back to `self.dct`; you only mutate the state of it.

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternative solution. Instead of using a `dict()`, I used a `multiprocessing.Manager.dict()` and it worked as expected.